# Symfony2 FormBuilder with Entity type with no values

Tags: symfony-2.1

I am using an entity type of form element in Symfony2's formbuilder.

```
 ->add('categories', 'entity', array('required' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
            'label'=>'Categories (select all that apply)',
            'class' => 'AcmeBundle:Category',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($profile) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->where('u.profile = :profile')
                    ->setParameter('profile', $profile)
                    ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
            }));
```

There is a case where the database query does not return any values, but Symfony2 still displays the label for the element.

How do I suppress the label altogether for cases where there are no entity results to display? Thanks!

Comment: What happens when say you assign the array to a variable, lets call it $categoryInputAttributes then before calling add() you do unset($categoryInputAttributes['label']); ?

Comment: That sounds like a solution-- basically run the query before building the form, and building it dynamically.  But I'm hoping there's a more Symfony-style approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improving the answer of @alainivars since my edit was rejected.

In your associated .twig file add this:

```
{% if not empty(entity.categories) %}
    {{ form_label(form.categories) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.categories) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.categories) }}
{% else %}
    {% do form.categories.setRendered %}
{% endif %}
```

That will display it only if it is not empty and marked the setRendered on the field so it doesn't show on the form_rest, thus bypassing your problem.

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't work but this first line does: {% if form.categories is not empty %}

Answer (score 1):

In your associated .twig file add this:

```
{% if not empty(entity.categories) %}
    {{ form_label(form.categories) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.categories) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.categories) }}
{% endif %}
```

That will display it only if it is not empty

Comment: I think the twig syntax is "if entity.categories is not empty".  But that still doesn't work, it still displays the label.

Comment: It is still rendering the main entity "Categories" label with the "form_rest".  This almost seems like a Sf2 bug.